# How can I zoom in on this circle so I can count the individual pixels?

Tags: java

How can I zoom in on this circle so I can count the individual pixels?
I'm drawing circles in Minecraft and I want a good template for each circle.

```
// Import the basic graphics classes.
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class BasicJPanel2 extends JPanel{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// Create a constructor method
  public BasicJPanel2(){
    super();
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    // draw a circle
    int upperLeft_x = 10;
    int upperLeft_y = 20;
    int width = 65;
    int height = 65;
    g.drawOval(upperLeft_x,upperLeft_y,width,height); // draw circle

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of addressing this problem is to cast the Graphics object to Graphics2D, then use the scale(double, double) method to zoom.

```
// zooms in by a factor of 5 - call this method before rendering the circle
g2.scale(5, 5);
```